# Issue with trigger for archiving

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Trying to make a trigger that puts data into an archive table when a column called `COMPLETION_STATUS` goes from incomplete to complete, the dbms is a placeholder for the insert but I'm getting the following errors in the if statement

> Error(6,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol enter code here"SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type      current cursor delete    exists prior The symbol "begin" was substituted for "SELECT" to continue.
>
> Error(9,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:     * & - + ; / at for mod remainder rem  and    or group having intersect minus order start union where    connect || multiset The symbol ";" was substituted for "IF" to continue.
>
> Error(13,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

Code:

```
create or replace TRIGGER ARCHIVING_TRIG 
BEFORE UPDATE OF COMPLETION_STATUS ON PROJECT_DATA

BEGIN
DECLARE COMPLETION_STATUS1 VARCHAR2(9);
SELECT COMPLETION_STATUS into COMPLETION_STATUS1
FROM PROJECT_DATA WHERE COMPLETION_STATUS = 'complete'

IF COMPLETION_STATUS1 = 'complete'
THEN 
DBMS.output('123');
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: which data you want to put into another table? on update??

Answer (score 1):

- The `DECLARE` block should be before the `BEGIN` block.
- The `SELECT ...` statement needs to be terminated with a semicolon (`;`).
- It's `dbms_output.put_line()` not `dbms.output()`;
- You're trying to assign the result of a query that potentially can return more than one row to a scalar variable.
- The rows selected from `project_data` have no relation to the one(s) that triggered the trigger.

I suggest you use something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER archiving_trig
               AFTER UPDATE
                     ON project_data
               FOR EACH ROW
               WHEN (old.completion_status <> 'complete'
                     AND new.completion_status = 'complete')
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Trigger fired for ID ' || :new.id);
END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d27af7d60648097d49e08d5667caa739)

- I think maybe `AFTER` is the better time, because you want to archive the row after the status was successfully changed.
- Because of the `WHEN` the trigger will only fire if `completion_status` has been changed from something other than `'complete'` to `'complete'`. But you maybe also need to have a method of removing entries from the archive when the status changes from `'complete'` to something else. That isn't covered here.
- Declaring it as `FOR EACH ROW` let's you access the values of the updated row via `:new`. That way you don't need a query to select that nor a variable to select into.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this:

```
create table PROJECT_DATA_NEW as select * from PROJECT_DATA where 1=2;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ARCHIVING_TRIG 
AFTER UPDATE
   ON PROJECT_DATA
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
status number;
BEGIN
status:=0;
select 1 into status from PROJECT_DATA where 
:new.COMPLETION_STATUS='complete' and 
:old.COMPLETION_STATUS='incomplete'

if (status=1) then
insert into PROJECT_DATA_NEW values(:old.column1,
:old.column2,
:old.column3,
:old.column4,
:old.column5,....etc); 
end if;
END;

/
```